# Quickly change my current location in the QGIS 3 browser

Tags: qgis-3, qgis-browser

I use Windows Explorer to manage the contents of the folder, and the fastest way to change my current folder in different applications is to copy the folder path and paste it into the browser tab of another application. But I can't find any input boxes in QGIS 3 browser to insert the path to the folder.

**There is a way to quickly change my current location in the QGIS 3 browser without manually pressing all of these <kbd>+</kbd> buttons on the browser tab?**

[image]

Comment: you can add a folder you have to enter frequently as favourite, not sure if that does help you?

Comment: Or you can simply drag & drop anything from Win Explorer into QGIS.

Comment: @Erik Thanks, but `drag & drop` is not suitable for all situations. For example in case of `GeoPackage` this action will add all the layers inside database.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way to do this is that, you can **Right click** on any folder that you want to use frequently, and then mark **"Add to Favorities"**. This will add it to the favorite tab that is present on top. This can help to quickly navigate to that directory.

I did not see any other option, that you can use to mark for quick navigation in browser of QGIS 3.

I hope it helps.

Comment: You can also right-click on the Favorites header to "Add a Directory...", which opens the regular file browser. There you can paste in a file path to add that folder as a favorite.